# Can AR feature be embedded within a native application instead of stand alone AR application using ARCore?

Tags: arcore

From the available documentation, https://developers.google.com/ar/
All the examples(Including Unity) begins with the scene view. It is good for experimenting.However, I want know if ARcore can be integrated with existing  native application seamlessly. Is it possible to embed the AR feature using ARcore as a separate activity and not have a seperate application that begins with the scene?

Comment: yes, a separate activity is possible.